# How do you (line by line) read multiple .gz files that are inside a zipped folder in Python without creating temporary files?

Tags: python, compression, gzip, zip

Let's say you have a zipped folder which contains many .gz files (the actual contents are just compressed CSVs). How do I directly read them line-by-line without first extracting into a temporary folder or files? It doesn't matter how they're stored once loaded in Python, I imagine naturally it would just be lists of strings, one string per row, but that's not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
import gzip

with ZipFile("storage.zip") as zf:
     files =  zf.namelist()
     for file in files:
         with zf.open(file) as f:
             with gzip.open(f, 'rt') as g:
                 for line in g.readlines():
                     print(line)
```